# Using SignalR to notify clients when scheduled events occur

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that displays current staffing data, and uses SignalR to notify connected clients when staffing changes occur.  This is working great for real-time events ("I need to leave work now."), but now I need to handle scheduled events where a staffing change will happen in the future.

That is, an event may be scheduled to occur in 3 hours and 27 minutes ("I need to leave work at 4pm") or even 3 months from now.  When the event occurs, connected clients should be notified in order to display correct staffing data to the end users.  Of course, the future may change, and a solution would need to account for scheduled events being canceled or modified.

I would love to find a clean way to do this that doesn't involve frequent polling from clients to learn of upcoming events, a thread on the server side that sleeps, etc.

Comment: What about creating a server-side scheduled job. The server can then invoke the signalR hub to push the notification to the client(s). Quartz.NET is good for these kinds of things

Comment: ^ Recommend above. It seems like you're trying to put the Scheduling work on your web server, which shouldn't be there. Use a separate Task/Scheduler to do the work, and maybe use `[Authorize]`  on hub methods that fire events to make sure only the scheduler can call them. clients will only be able to receive events.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small windows service that takes care of scheduling. Then use a service bus to signal the web server for example

http://ayende.com/blog/3752/rhino-service-bus

On the web server you can use https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy
to forward the messages directly to the clients